# I am trying to execute a procedure in CodeIgniter from SQL server, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter

I am trying to execute the stored procedure from my SQL server database and make it print a list, what is the best way to print it out?

This is my Model:

```
class Categories_Model extends CI_Model
{
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

function get_categories()
{
    $sql = 'exec spGetCategoriesByID';
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    $result = $query->result();
    return $result;
}
}
```

This is my Controller:

```
class Categories_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->database();
}

public function categories_list()
{
    $this->load->model('Categories_Model');
    $cat_result = $this->Categories_Model->get_categories();
    $data['catlist'] = $cat_result;
    $this->load->view('categories',$data);
}
}
```

Comment: Don't know about SQL server but in Oracle only functions can return data, procedures can only manipulate data.

Comment: assume that your sp don`t need parameter, try `$query = $this->db->query("exec spGetCategoriesByID()");`

Comment: `$this->categories_model->get_categories()` and `$this->load->model('categories_model')` should be written in **all lower-case**; and the class name should only have the FIRST letter capitalized on its file name as well as here:  `class Categories_model extends CI_Model`.

Comment: Thanks, this definitely helped. I am new to using a mvc styled framework in php. So I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try getting the error like this:

```
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
echo 'Error #'.$this->db->_error_number().': '.$this->db->_error_message();
die();
```